# Possible values of $\dfrac{25}{\cos^2x+8\sin x \cos x - 5 \sin^2 x+2}=3\sin y+4\cos y$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

In this problem I have to find the range of possible values of $$t=\dfrac{25}{\cos^2x+8\sin x \cos x - 5 \sin^2 x+2}=3\sin y+4\cos y$$

I have attempted a full solution below but am unsure if it is correct.

**My attempt:**

As $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A, \cos 2A=\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A \text{ and } \cos^2A+\sin^2A=1$, we can rewrite $\text{LHS}$ as

$$t=\dfrac{25}{3\cos2x+4\sin2x}$$

If $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)$

$$\require{cancel} t=\dfrac{\cancel{25}5}{\cancel{5}\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\cos2x+\dfrac{4}{5}\sin2x\right)}=\dfrac{5}{\cos \theta\cos2x+\sin \theta\sin2x}=\dfrac{5}{\cos(\theta -2x)}$$

Also $$t=5\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\sin y + \dfrac{4}{5} \cos y\right)=5(\cos \theta \sin y + \sin \theta \cos y)=5\sin (\theta+2y)$$

Since $$-1 \le \cos (\theta-2x)\le1 \implies \dfrac{1}{\cos(\theta-2x)}\le-1 \text{ or } 1 \le \dfrac{1}{\cos (\theta - 2x)} \implies \dfrac{5}{\cos(\theta-2x)}\le-5 \text{ or } 5 \le \dfrac{5}{\cos (\theta - 2x)}$$ $$\therefore t \in (-\infty,-5] \cup [5,\infty) \tag{1}$$

and $$-1 \le \sin (\theta + 2y) \le 1 \implies -5 \le 5\sin (\theta + 2y) \le 5$$ $$\therefore t \in [-5,5] \tag{2}$$

Taking intersection of values obtained in $(1)$ and $(2)$ $$\boxed{t=-5,5}$$

Is my attempt correct? Corrections/hints if not would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's correct. Except that you have represented the equation with $y$, which has already been used. Maybe use another variable.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Yes, thanks. I have edited it now.